# How can I get a 'unit test view' for gauge tests?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, gauge

I've run into a quite irritation problem in which I am able to run gauge automation tests with Intellij IDE, but can't seem to get the results displayed as I would like.

Expected:

[image: Expected]

Actual:

[image: Actual]

This is most likely a configuration issue, but I can't seem to be able to put my finger on it. I've googled the issue, but no luck.

```
$ gauge -v                                                                                                                                                                                                       system: ruby 2.3.7p456
Gauge version: 1.0.6

Plugins
-------
html-report (4.0.8)
java (0.7.2)
screenshot (0.0.1)
xml-report (0.2.1)
```

Please let me know if further data is required.

Thanks!!

EDIT(0): Gauge plugin for Intellij is installed already.

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA has no support for Gauge tests. You can [try a third-party plug-in](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7535-gauge/).

Comment: I have it installed already. Forgot to mention it.

Comment: You can contact the plug-in vendor and ask to support the tree view for the tests.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after scooping around deeper into git forums I found this particular answer: https://github.com/getgauge/Intellij-Plugin/issues/392#issuecomment-527854552 which solved my issue.

Regardless, wanted to thank everyone for their attention!